# overflow: auto or overflow: scroll. Scrollbar is shown but not working

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I tried to use the overflow:auto for a modal，and the scrollbar is shown but not working, wither with clicking and dragging or the wheel on the mouse.

```
.registerpop {
    position: relative;
    width: 35vw !important;
    height: 80vh !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML code too? It would be helpful for us to repro the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.